# Understanding a proof of concept

Tags: buffer-overflow, websocket

I found this report about a [buffer overflow vulnerability](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39882/)  in `websocify`. I do not understand how this line

```
$ curl http://example.com/$(python -c 'print "A"*5000')
```

triggers the vulnerability. I think the address will be expanded to `http://example.com/AAAAAA...`. I do not know how `websockify` relates to this.

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from the bulletin:

```
ws_ctx_t *do_handshake(int sock) {
    char handshake[4096], response[4096], sha1[29], trailer[17];
    [...]
    offset = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        len = ws_recv(ws_ctx, handshake+offset, 4096);
        if (len == 0) {
            handler_emsg("Client closed during handshake\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        offset += len;
        handshake[offset] = 0;
        if (strstr(handshake, "\r\n\r\n")) {
            break;
        }
        usleep(10);
    }
    [...]
}
```

- offset = 0
- ws_recv (ws_ctx, handshake + 0, 4096) => 4096
- offset = 4096
- handshake[4096] = 0; // out of bounds write.
- no double-CRLF found, loop
- ws_recv (ws_ctx, handshake + 4096, 4096) => entirely out of bounds write.

The loop seems to have been designed with the assumption that it would only loop due to receiving insufficent data.  By throwing gobs of data at it it looped anyways but after the first pass it no longer had properly constrained memory.

The 3rd parameter should have been `4096 - offset`, representing the amount of space remaining, not the total buffer space (since ws_recv didn't get the total buffer unless offset==0).  (Or they needed to reallocate, et cetera).

Comment: But comes to this the `curl` command? I do not know it, what I assume is that it fetches the web page. But in the example it becomes `http://example.com/AAA...` which is invalid.

Comment: Curl is a command line utility for making web requests. That just issues a GET to http://example.com/{5000 As}. The $(python ...) syntax is a unix command shell syntax, not curl.